# Laravel Lighthouse GraphQL create mutation without "input:"

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I'm looking a the documentation for Laravel Lighthouse and I am seeing two types of mutations.

- A mutation that includes the string `input:` [(found here)](https://lighthouse-php.com/4.8/eloquent/nested-mutations.html#belongs-to)

```graphql
mutation {
  createPost(input: { # <-- the "input:" I'm talking about
    title: "My new Post"
    author: {
      connect: 123
    }
  }){
    id
    author {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

And another mutation without the `input:` [(found here)](https://lighthouse-php.com/4.8/concepts/arg-resolvers.html#motivation)

```graphql
mutation CreateTaskWithNotes {
  createTask( # <-- no "input:" here
    id: 45
    name: "Do something"
    notes: [
      {
        content: "Foo bar",
        link: "http://foo.bar"
      },
      {
        content: "Awesome note"
      }
    ]
  ) {
    id
  }
}
```

My question is: How do I get the mutations without `input:` to work?

I try to copy (an modify) the examples from the documentation. But if I write a mutation like this:

```graphql
type Mutation {
    createTask(input: CreateTaskInput! @spread): Task! @create
}
```

When I try to omit `input:`, graphql-playground complains: "Field *createTask* argument *input* of type *CreateTaskInput* is required but not provided"

Now I try to change the schema to this:

```graphql
type Mutation {
    createTask(CreateTaskInput! @spread): Task! @create
}
```

But then the server gives a `ParseException`.

I do prefer the syntax without `input:` because that is a lot less repetitive.
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write a mutation without the `input`, also ommit the `@spread` directive. So:

```
type Mutation {
    createTask(
        id: ID
        name: String
    ): Task! @create
}
```

But I think it's a "best practices" to have that inside an `input`. Of course you can do wethever you want to do.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure what was best practice. Does this mean that the documentation is incorrect with the example without ```input```?

Comment: Sorry, where is the example without `input`? I don't see anything wrong...

Comment: I might be missing something here, but if I go to https://lighthouse-php.com/4.8/concepts/arg-resolvers.html and look at the second piece of code (```mutation CreateTaskWithNotes```), then it seems to me that this is a mutation without ```input```.

Comment: No, that's an example of a Client Request (what you will write in Apollo)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
type Mutation {
    createTask: Task! @create
}
```

https://newbedev.com/index.php/graphql-mutations-without-arguments